# need noRepaint() when i validate()

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, repaint, jscrollbar

I have a JScrollPane with a View. I'm doing a chat application , it's why i need to have my ScrollBar to the Maximum(). To get the right Maximum of the View i have to validate before. When I validate my ScrollPane an automatic repaint is doing. I don't want this repaint because it makes a double repaint when i set the ScrollBar to the Maximum : when the ScrollBar is at the top and a another when it is a the bottom.

my code :

```
Main.getWindow().getMainPanel().getScrollPaneCenter().validate();
scrollPaneCenter.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPaneCenter.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
```

PS : I want to disable the repaint of my conponent or maybe you have a solution to have a reversed JScrollPane( to always have the ScrollBar to Bottom) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm doing a chat application

I'm guessing your are using a a JTextArea or JTextPane.

> it's why i need to have my ScrollBar to the Maximum().

You don't need to validate or set the scrollbar manually. You juat append the text to the bottom of the Document. See [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for a couple of solutions.

Comment: I'm using a JPanel inside my JScrollPane. I'll try JTextPane do you think it's the bes way to just display Some Component ? ( I have made Bubble for the conversation in the chat )

Comment: i would like to do something like that but it's not working . ( because of the layout ? )                                  `JTextPane pan = new JTextPane();<br/>
pan.setBackground(new Color(1, 0, 0, 0));<br/>
pan.setLayout(null);<br/>
int taillePanel = 0;<br/>
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {<br/>
JButton test = new JButton("Button number : " + i);<br/>
test.setBorderPainted(false);<br/>
test.setBounds(0, (i * 75), 250, 75);<br/>
taillePanel += 75;<br/>
pan.insertComponent(test);}<br/>
pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, taillePanel));
JScrollPane scrollPaneCenter = new JScrollPane(pan);`